# PBC library: group of composite order for pairing operation

Tags: encryption, pairings

How to generate composite order group using PBC library? With PBC library, `element_init_G1(g,pairing)` statement creates element $g$ for group of prime order.
I want to know how element of composite order group is created.

Comment: Pairings of Type A1 support groups of composite order, but [PBC](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch05s01.html) doesn't seem to support the generation of group orders with more than two prime factors. You can see how [jPBC does it](http://sourceforge.net/p/jpbc/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/jpbc-plaf/src/main/java/it/unisa/dia/gas/plaf/jpbc/pairing/a1/TypeA1CurveGenerator.java). Anyway, this site is generally not for programming problems. [so] is more appropriate for those.

Comment: Relic(https://github.com/relic-toolkit/relic) is probably a better library to use than PBC. It's faster and actually still under  active development.  I think it supports composite order groups, but I am not sure.